# insert xml attributes texts inside json file

Tags: python, json, xml, loops

I am iterating over an XML file to insert some of its attributes inside a JSON to develop a Corpus. For some reason, when inserting the date and the body of the XML it always inserts the same text inside the JSON line

The XML file format (I'm trying to get the title, timestamp and text from all the pages):

```
<page>
<title>MediaWiki:Monobook.js</title>
<ns>8</ns>
<id>4</id>
<revision>
  <id>45582</id>
  <parentid>45581</parentid>
  <timestamp>2007-09-20T03:20:46Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>Superzerocool</username>
    <id>404</id>
  </contributor>
  <comment>Limpiando</comment>
  <model>javascript</model>
  <format>text/javascript</format>
  <text bytes="34" xml:space="preserve">/* Utilizar MediaWiki:Common.js */</text>
  <sha1>5dy7xlkatqg5epjzrq48br6yeh5uu34</sha1>
 </revision>
</page>
```

My code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   path = 'local path'
   tree = ET.parse(path)

   root = tree.getroot()

with open("C:/Users/User/Documents/Github/News-Corpus/corpus.json", "w") as f:
    for page in tqdm(root.findall('page')):
        title = page.find('title').text
        dictionary = {}
        dictionary["title"] = title
        for revision in root.iter('revision'):
            timestamp = revision.find('timestamp').text
            dictionary["timestamp"] = timestamp
            body = revision.find('text').text
            dictionary["body"] = body
        f.write(json.dumps(dictionary))
        f.write("\n")
```

The output I get:

```
{"title": "MediaWiki:Monobook.js", "timestamp": "2022-09-16T13:07:15Z", "body": "Los pasajeros les fue devuelta el importe de su billete de vuelo perdida?"}
{"title": "MediaWiki:Administrators", "timestamp": "2022-09-16T13:07:15Z", "body": "Los pasajeros les fue devuelta el importe de su billete de vuelo perdida?"}
{"title": "MediaWiki:Allmessages", "timestamp": "2022-09-16T13:07:15Z", "body": "Los pasajeros les fue devuelta el importe de su billete de vuelo perdida?"}
{"title": "MediaWiki:Allmessagestext", "timestamp": "2022-09-16T13:07:15Z", "body": "Los pasajeros les fue devuelta el importe de su billete de vuelo perdida?"}
{"title": "MediaWiki:Allpagessubmit", "timestamp": "2022-09-16T13:07:15Z", "body": "Los pasajeros les fue devuelta el importe de su billete de vuelo perdida?"}
```

As you can see, I always get the same timestamp and the same body, does anyone know why this happens? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `tdqm`?

Comment: That is not a valid JSON. Consider building a list of dictionaries and then save to .json. Also, try [`iterfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iterfind) vs `iter` for subelements.

Comment: I use tqdm for the script to show a progress bar of the process so I know how much time is left @JackFleeting